# ROS Kinetic Installation- Key not imported

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using the instructions given [Ubuntu install of ROS Kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu). I am getting this error in step 1.3. I tried other key servers too. How to solve this error?

```
 $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
Executing: /tmp/tmp.fSeKmpG9h6/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
--recv-key
421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
gpg: requesting key B01FA116 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key B01FA116: "ROS Builder <rosbuild@ros.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273711/ros-kinetic-installation--key-not-imported/) by [Pratik_Patil](https://answers.ros.org/users/32338/pratik_patil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That does not appear to be an error, it is saying that you already had the key installed so nothing is changed. You should be able to continue the installation process.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pratik_Patil](https://answers.ros.org/users/32338/pratik_patil/) on 2017-10-21**:
Thanks. But this is weird. After installing Ubuntu, this is the first time I am installing ROS. Where did the key come from?